# How can I build a neural network with 2 independent sets of weights and 2 losses?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Consider the following neural network:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.blue_1 = nn.Linear(2, 10)
        self.red_1 = nn.Linear(10, 5)
        self.blue_2 = nn.Linear(5, 4)
        self.red_2 = nn.Linear(4, 3)
        self.blue_3 = nn.Linear(3, 2)
        self.red_3 = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.blue_1(x))
        x = self.red_1(x)
        x = self.blue_2(x)
        x = self.red_2(x)
        x = self.blue_3(x)
        x = self.red_3(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())

features = torch.rand((10,2)) #10 inputs, each of 2D

for epoch in range(3):
    x = net(features)
    loss = torch.sum(torch.randint(0,10,(10,)) - x)
    loss.backward()
    print(loss)
```

I have 2 independent sets of weights, call them `blues` (e.g `self.blue_1`) and `reds` (e.g `self.red_1`). These 2 sets need to be multiplied in some combination (e.g see `forward` method). However, in comparison to what I have above I need the `blue` weights to be updated according to a certain loss function (e.g `loss_blue = some_loss_function`, and the `red` weights to be updated according to another loss function (e.g `torch.sum(torch.randint(0,10,(10,)) - x)`).

It's important that the `red` loss doesn't propagate through the `blue` weights and vice versa.

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking to even break it into 2 neural networks but I'm not sure if 1. it's the best approach, and 2. how to do it using that approach.

Comment: Even with a single set of weights: the blue ones. I don't see how `number of red weights with a value above 5` can be differentiable, in other words, you can't propagate on `loss_blue`.

Comment: @Ivan that was just an example (apparently a bad one), you can choose any other loss function that you want as long as the other conditions hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be, in four steps:

1. Do the first inference to compute `loss_blue`.
2. Backpropagate from `loss_blue` and update the blue parameters,
3. Then infer again to compute `loss_red` with the updated blue weights
4. Backpropagate from `loss_red` and update the red parameters.

This is similar to how you would go about training a GAN alternating between generator and discriminator with successive backward passes and updates. Having two optimizers handling the two sets of parameters makes it easier to use. Don't forget to clear the gradients before backpropagating so one loss doesn't pollute the other parameters with its gradient.

---

Something like this should work out:

```
net = Model()

optim_blue = optim.Adam(net.blues()) # fetch all blue parameters
optim_red = optim.Adam(net.reds())   # fetch all red parameters

features = torch.rand((10,2)) #10 inputs, each of 2D

# # inference, backprop and update on blue params
out = net(features)
loss_blue = torch.sum(torch.randint(0,10,(10,)) - out)

optim_red.zero_grad()
optim_blue.zero_grad()
loss_blue.backward()
optim_blue.step()

# # inference backprop and update on red params
out = net(features)
loss_red = out.mean()

optim_red.zero_grad()
optim_blue.zero_grad()
loss_red.backward()
optim_red.step()
```

---

*Edit based on comment*:

> 1. How do you specify which parameters/layers will be in the `optimizer(optim_blue = optim.Adam(net.blues()))`. Is it something along the lines of `optim_blue = optim.Adam([net. blue_1, net. blue_2...])`?

Yes, something like that. For defining the optimizers, you can for example create two functions inside your model: `reds` and `blues`.

```
    def reds(self):
        return [*self.red_1.parameters(),
                *self.red_2.parameters(),
                *self.red_3.parameters()]

    def blues(self):
        return [*self.blue_1.parameters(),
                *self.blue_2.parameters(),
                *self.blue_3.parameters()]
```

> 2. What makes the gradients separated when you call `loss_blue.backward()`? That is, what stops them to flow through the reds? Is that the purpose of the 2 optimizers?

When `loss_blue.backward`, the gradient flows through all parameters of the model, including the red parameters. What makes all the difference is indeed the fact that `optim_blue` will only update the blue parameters, not the red ones.

Comment: Interesting. A few questions. 1. How do you specify which parameters/layers will be in the optimizer(`optim_blue = optim.Adam(net.blues())`). Is it something along the lines of `optim_blue = optim.Adam([net. blue_1, net. blue_2...])`? 2. What makes the gradients separated when you call `loss_blue.backward()`? That is, what stops them to flow through the `reds`? Is that the purpose of the 2 optimizers?

Comment: Your two remarks are accurate, I have edited my answer above with some clarifications on those points.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks a lot! Last silly question, what does the `*` before `*self.blue_1.parameters()` do?

Comment: @Penguin It unpacks the generator into the list, it's just a quick way of "merging" the two parameters generators.